# How can I have more than one click function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div on the left side of my page and a div on the right side. I want both of the to animate to a "hidden" and "shown" position, like side menus. I managed to get one working like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header-tab").click(function () {
        if ($(".header").position().left == 0) {
            $(".header").animate({left:'-150px'}, "slow");
            $(".header-tab").animate({left:'0'}, "slow");
        } else {
            $(".header").animate({left:'0'}, "slow");
            $(".header-tab").animate({left:'150px'}, "slow");
        }
    });
});
```

But I did this to have both left and right sides working and only the left side works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header-tab").click(function () {
        if ($(".header").position().left == 0) {
            $(".header").animate({left:'-150px'}, "slow");
            $(".header-tab").animate({left:'0'}, "slow");
        } else {
            $(".header").animate({left:'0'}, "slow");
            $(".header-tab").animate({left:'150px'}, "slow");
        }
    });

    $(".aside-tab").click(function () {
        if ($(".aside").position().right == 0) {
            $(".aside").animate({right:'-150px'}, "slow");
            $(".aside-tab").animate({right:'0'}, "slow");
        } else {
            $(".aside").animate({right:'0'}, "slow");
            $(".aside-tab").animate({right:'150px'}, "slow");
        }
    });
});
```

So can someone please tell me where or how I would add the second click function (aside)?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="header-tab"></div>

        <div class="container"></div>

        <div class="aside"></div>
        <div class="aside-tab"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML as well. Saves guessing :)

Comment: I would suggest using a boolean to determine if the side is open or closed rather than checking if the position == 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple issues with your code, First as you have *two* `.aside` divs, when clicking on any of the `.aside-tab` divs you need to specify which aside you want to slide. i.e suppose I clicked on the *right* `div.aside-tab` and click event got fired, since you have *two* `.aside` divs this condition:

```
if($(".aside").position().right == 0)
```

will look confusing, which `.aside` of them? also this line:
    $(".aside").animate({right:'-150px'}, "slow");

the above line will animate them both? you need a way to know if it was the right or the left one, I've added `id`s, and depending on the value of the `id` I know whether it was the right or the left one, and I animate the corresponding one.

Also, IMHO,   I don't think this `aside.position().right` returns a value, as I know it is either `.left` or `.top`, so for the right one we will animate according to full window width, or full window width - 150, which is the width of the `.aside`

it should be something like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/o0q89t7f/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header-tab").click(function () {
        if ($(".header").position().left == 0) {
            $(".header").animate({left:'-150px'}, "slow");
            $(".header-tab").animate({left:'0'}, "slow");
        } else {
            $(".header").animate({left:'0'}, "slow");
            $(".header-tab").animate({left:'150px'}, "slow");
        }
    });

    $(".aside-tab").click(function () {
        var id, aside;
        
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.replace('-btn', '');
        aside = $('#' + id + '-side');
        if(id == 'left'){
         if(aside.position().left == 0){
           aside.animate({left:'-150px'}, "slow"); 
          } else {
           aside.animate({left:'0'}, "slow");
          }
        } else {
         
         var winW = $(window).width();
         if(aside.position().left == winW - 150){
           aside.animate({left: winW}, "slow"); 
          } else {
           
           aside.animate({left:winW - 150}, "slow");
          }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.aside-tab{
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  z-index:1000;
}
#left-btn{
  background-color:tomato;
  left:5px;
}
#right-btn{
  right:5px;
  background-color:green;
}
.aside{
  height:100vh;
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:10;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
#left-side{
  background-color:skyblue;
  left:-150px;
}
#right-side{
  background-color:orange;
  left:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="header-tab"></div>

<div class="container"></div>

<div id="left-side" class="aside"></div>
<div id="left-btn" class="aside-tab"></div>

<div id="right-side" class="aside"></div>
<div id="right-btn" class="aside-tab"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE:** Also you may consider using `element.on('click',` instead of `element.click` as [JCD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4897779/jcd) mentioned in his answer, not only because of the `element.off()` method but also because with `element.on()` you can attach more than one event, supposing an `input type="text"` field it could be just like:

```
$('#my-input').on('input change blur keypress', function(){...});
```

which can be useful sometimes.

Comment: It is a little different than what I had in mind, BUT I love your set up better! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

As of jQuery 1.7 the `.on()` function is the preferred way to attach event handlers to elements. One reason for this is that the corresponding `.off()` function makes it easy to manage which event handlers are attached.

If you want multiple click event handlers on an element, just string them together with `.on()`.

```
$("#some-element").on("click", eventHandlerOne).on("click", eventHandlerTwo);
// both event handlers will fire from a click
```

Later you can remove handlers individually if you want

```
$("#some-element").off("click", eventHandlerTwo); // eventHandlerOne still active
```

Or remove ALL event handlers of a type:

```
$("#some-element").off("click"); // no more click event handlers!
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this answers your question since I may have misinterpreted it but hopefully it helps.